# Add custom logic in CreateView to not show the add form if a condition is met

Tags: django, django-views

How do I add custom logic in a class based view ?

urls.py:
`path('books/add', views.AddBook.as_view(), name='add_book'),`

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=2048)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
MAX_BOOKS = 5
class AddBook(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Book
    
    """
    if user has reached MAX_BOOKS
    
    books = Book.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if len(books) == MAX_BOOKS
        template_name = 'books/restrict_book.html'
        and send in some data like { 'error_msg': 'You cannot add further books' }
    """

    form_class = BookForm
    # fields = ['title']
    template_name = 'books/add_book.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        super(AddBook, self).form_valid(form)
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count()` method  to count queryset and compare with the max books value.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count() >= MAX_BOOKS:
        return render(self.request, 'books/restrict_book.html')
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(AddBook, self).form_valid(form)
```

EDIT: If you want to render another template if Book count limit reached before submitting the form you can override `get` method also.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   if Book.objects.filter(user=request.user).count() >= MAX_BOOKS:
        return render(request, 'books/restrict_book.html')
   return render(request, self.template, {'form':self.form_class()})
```

Comment: But this works only *after* submitting the form. I don't want a user to add the details in the form and then shown an error message like "Books count limit reached". Is there a way to show the other template before the form is shown ?

Comment: This works, but now `return render(request, self.template_name)` doesn't show the form when less than MAX_BOOKS - the ` {{ form.title.label }}` and others are empty.

Comment: You need to pass the form as a context @anjanesh answer updated

Comment: Thanks. I did `return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': BookForm() })` which also worked but was not sure if this was the correct implementation. Thanks again.